# The css settings of my table in has disappeared after including the php file, in the place of header

Tags: php, html, css, printing

I’m working on my prices.php page, where it has a table. I also have created a include folder and added, header.php and footer.php file in it. Suddenly, the css settings of my table in prices.php has disappeared after including the php file, in the place of header.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, 
       maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />


                          <?php include("include/header.php");?>

<hr class="bordered" />
<div class="container">
 <div class="row"> 

  <!-- Content -->
  <div class="span9"> 

  <!-- Breadcrumb -->
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pages</a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
    <li class="active">About US</li>
  </ul>
  <h1>Price <span>Details</span></h1>

  <p>
  <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ProductName</th>
        <th>PackQty</th>
        <th>Price</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>SingleSide Gloss v.card</td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td>450 Rs</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Front & Back Gloss v.card</td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td>750 Rs</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>SingleSide Matt. v.card</td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td>450 Rs</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>SingleSide Syn. v.card </td>
        <td>500</td>
        <td>550 Rs</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>SingleSide Syn. v.card</td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td>950 Rs</td>
    </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Spot Lamin. v.card - Single Side (1000) </td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td>1100 Rs</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Spot Lamin. v.card - Double Side (1000)     </td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td>1850 Rs</td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>Die Cut V. Cards Matt (1000)</td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td>1950 Rs</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>LetterHead Ex.Bond 70 Gsm 5 PADS (500 nos)</td>
        <td>500</td>
        <td>1300 Rs</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>LetterHead Ex.Bond  80 Gsm WITH PAD ( 1000)</td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td>2100 Rs</td>
    </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Letter Pad Ex.Bond 70 Gsm Loose Sheet(500)</td>
        <td>500</td>
        <td>1100 Rs</td>
    </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Letter Pad Ex.Bond 80 Gsm Loose Sheet(1000)</td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td>1900 Rs</td>
    </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Envelope (9x4) 80gsm Exe. Bond(1000nos.) </td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td>2100 Rs</td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>A4 Size 100gsm Art Paper One Side 1000nos) </td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td>1700 Rs</td>
    </tr>


      <tr>
        <td>A4 Size 100gsm Art Paper Double Side 1000nos) </td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td>2100 Rs</td>
    </tr>


     <tr>
        <td>A4 SIZE 130 GSM Art Paper ONE SIDE 1000 NOS</td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td>2200 Rs</td>
    </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A4 Size 130gsm Art Paper Double Side 1000nos) </td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td>2900 Rs</td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>A4 Size 170gsm Art Paper (ONE SIDE - 1000nos) </td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td>2500 Rs</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>A4 Size 170gsm Art Paper(D/s SIDE - 1000nos) </td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td>3650 Rs</td>
    </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Kovil Viboothi Covers (100gsm Art) (4000 Nos.)  </td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td>2900 Rs</td>
    </tr>




    </tbody>
  </table>
   <div style="clear:both; height:20px;"></div>

  <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ProductName</th>
        <th>Details</th>
        <th>Price</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Responsive website ( Mobile + Laptop + destop)</td>
        <td>Domain Name + Web Hosting + (RWD) Website + Email Id </td>
        <td>Rs.10,000</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Normal website</td>
        <td>Domain Name + Web Hosting + Email Id </td>
        <td>Rs.5,000</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Social media sites (  , etc...)</td>
        <td> </td>
        <td>Rs.3,500</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Sms marketing (1 lakh sms)</td>
        <td>(1 lakh sms + 1 Year) </td>
        <td>Rs.5,500</td>
    </tr>


    </tbody>
    </table>

     </p>

     </div>

      <!-- Sidebar -->
   <?php include("include/sidebar.php");?>
   </div>
   </div>

    <!-- Small Banners
   <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    </div>
     </div>

   <!-- Footer Links -->

   <?php include("include/footer.php");?>

  </body>
  </html>


   Here is my header.php file

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
    type="text/css" />

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" />
      <!-- Scripts -->
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-  
      1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js">

     </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexslider.min.js"> 
       </script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.min.js"> 
         </script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
       </head>
      <body>

   <!-- Header -->
   <div class="header">
   <div class="container">
   <div class="row"> 

  <!-- Secondary Menu -->
  <!-- <ul class="nav nav-pills span6">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Wish List</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Shopping Cart</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Checkout</a></li>
 </ul>-->

 <!-- Header Cart -->
  <div class="cart"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i>
  <p>&euro; 0,00 <span>( 0 )</span></p>

  <!-- Header Cart Content -->
  <div class="cart-content">
  <div class="mini-cart-info">
    <h3>Shopping Cart</h3>
    <p class="empty">Empty cart</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Currency -->
 <ul class="nav nav-pills currency">
 <li class="active"><a href="#">&euro;</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">$</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">&pound;</a></li>
 </ul>

 <!-- Header Login -->
 <p class="log-reg"><a href="#">Sign In</a> <a href="#">Register</a></p>
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="wrap-box"></div>
<!-- Logo --> 
<a href="#" id="logo"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" /></a> 


<!-- Main Navbar -->
<hr class="bordered" />
<div class="navbar-cont">
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="span12">
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container"><a class="btn btn-navbar" data- 
 toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse"><i   
   class="icon-align-justify"></i></a>
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">




      <?php include("include/navigation.php");?>




        <!-- Navbar Search -->
        <form action="" class="header-search">
          <fieldset>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
            <button><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Use some good editor that will allow you to see matching tags and code indentation

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. I found multiple errors in your file.

1. There is not closing HEAD  tag, so essentially everything comes under head tag.
2. You close BODY tag, but I think you forgot to open it.

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html> 
       <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />    
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <!-- its better to import CSS js files here if they will be used by all elements in the page -->

     </head>
    <body>

      <!-- import php files here and do other stuffs -->

         <?php include("include/header.php");?> 
     <hr class="bordered" /> <div class="container"> <div class="row">     
    <!-- rest of your code --> 

    </body>
   </html>
   ```